# Angular build - Refresh goes to 404, Is there any way to resolve this without implementing the HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, hash-location-strategy

Angular build is hosted in the server and is working properly, except, on refreshing any of the page, it goes to web server **404** page.

While searching for the solution, everybody suggests the **HashLocationStrategy**. Is there any other way to resolve this so that the hash symbol will not appear in the url.

Webserver: Apache.

Note: One solution is to use .htaccess to redirect the 404 error response to angular build's index.html, But in this case the account activation lik clicked from the registered mails also will go to the index.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the rewrite engine in apache. You can enable it by below command

```
**sudo a2enmod rewrite**
```

Add below content to the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

It will resolve the routing issue, You can redirect to the Home or index component when there is no route in your application from angular routes but writing 404 error document page and redirect to index.html is not good.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is worked for the main routing like dashboard,But for the inner routing like users/scadmin is not working.

Comment: It will work for inner routes also..do hav any authguards etc..in ur route..? can you tell wht was the error getting for inner routes..?

Comment: It's throwing 404 itself